# random "ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list" error in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

So I have a small game written in python, if you saw my previous question you know it is a "space invaders" clone.

So nearly everything is running smoothly right now except for a random error popping out once in a while. This is completely random, it can occur after some bullets have been fired, or it may not occur at all.

I have this code:

```
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.attack()
        if bullet.posy<=-20:
            bullet_draw=False
        if bullet_draw==True:
            bullet.draw()
        for enemy in enemies:
            if bullet.sprite.rect.colliderect(enemy.sprite.rect):
                enemy.health-=1
                bullets.remove(bullet)
                bullet_draw=False
            else:
                bullet_draw=True
```

Sometimes it gives me the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Programming\space invaders\space.py", line 280, in <module>
    bullets.remove(bullet)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Please note that this error is completely random; even if it is not, I cannot trace its origin though. Any help as to how to eliminate it?

Comment: In general, catching the error and then using the post-mortem debugger (`import pdb; pdb.post_mortem()`) is a good way of figuring it out. During development I usually have a catch-all try-except clause around the entry point of my program, so that I can debug even unforseen problems right away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your bullet is hitting multiple enemies. You need to `break` out of the `enemies` loop.

Comment: Removing items from a list the OP is iterating over will also cause problems.

Comment: @DSM: True, but that's easy to deal with. `for bullet in bullets[:]:`

Comment: Done! By the way, the `continue` goes right after `bullet_draw=True` indented under `for bullet in bullets` right?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: sure, but when I hit enter I hadn't seen F.J.'s update which fixed it. :^)

Answer (score 5):

Try changing it to the following:

```
    for bullet in bullets[:]:    # this is changed, iterating over a copy
        bullet.attack()
        if bullet.posy<=-20:
            bullet_draw=False
        if bullet_draw==True:
            bullet.draw()
        for enemy in enemies:
            if bullet.sprite.rect.colliderect(enemy.sprite.rect):
                enemy.health-=1
                bullets.remove(bullet)
                bullet_draw=False
                break            # this is added, prevents multiple removes
            else:
                bullet_draw=True
```

Note the two comments I added that show the changes, the `break` is necessary because a single bullet might be hitting multiple enemies, which would cause `bullets.remove(bullet)` to be called twice, which is causing the traceback you are seeing.

The first change is necessary because removing elements from a list while iterating can result in some unexpected consequences because you will end up skipping over some elements during the iteration.  The following code illustrates this:

```
>>> data = range(10)
>>> for x in data:
...     data.remove(x)
...
>>> data
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Even though the code looks like it should remove every element from the list, it only removes every other because the list indices are changing during the iteration.